# Trigger bulkification when adding errors

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

**Snippet 1:**

```
trigger AccountValidationTrigger on Account(before update){
    for(Account accObj: Trigger.new){
      if(accObj.Some_Flag__c != TRUE){
        accObj.addError('Some flag should be true');  
      }
    }
}
```

**Snippet 2**:

```
trigger AccountValidationTrigger on Account(before update){
    List<Account> errorAcctsList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account accObj: Trigger.new){
      if(accObj.Some_Flag__c != TRUE){
        errorAcctsList.add(accObj);
      }
    }
    for(Account accObj: errorAcctsList){
        accObj.addError('Some flag should be true');
    }
}
```

Given the above two code snippets, which of the above is a best practice to use in trigger when adding validation logic.

Most of the best practices for trigger bulkification are about reducing number of DML statements but I couldn't find any example on what is the best practice to follow in above situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of bulkification is to perform an operation (such as a SOQL query) so that a set of records are returned together to help performance. This avoids running into governor limits which in turn are (often) a guard against repeating expensive operations. In the query example, returning 101 records in one request is: one request from the app server to the the database, one query plan generation, one query execution and one response from the database back to the app server. Making 101 separate queries would require all those steps to be repeated 101 times.

There is no need to arrange code executed locally in the app server using similar patterns. Generally simple code that is easily understood is best and [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) is the root of all evil. So the simpler pattern "snippet 1" is the way to go.

(By the way I'm saying "generally" here because in reality there are rarely "best practices" in the sense that a practice is universally "best". There are often several factors at play and what is best in one situation might not be best in another.)

**PS**

Before introducing design patterns into your code have a think about some of the pros and cons - see e.g. [When should I use—and not use—design patterns?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49379/when-should-i-use-and-not-use-design-patterns)

Comment: thought-provoking ..

Answer (score 3):

Fun fact, if you adopt the latter pattern, you can implement a library like [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) to do the filtering for you.

```
public with sharing class AccountService
{
    public static Select.Filter isFlagged()
    {
        return Select.Field.isEqual(Account.Some_Flag__c, true);
    }
    public static void validateFlaggedAccounts(List<Account> flaggedAccounts)
    {
        for (Account flaggedAccount : flaggedAccounts)
            flaggedAccount.addError('message');
    }
}
```

Then in your trigger you can just do:

```
AccountServices.validateFlaggedAccounts(
    AccountServices.isFlagged().filter(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap)
);
```

One *huge advantage* of this pattern is it's way easier to test. You can test the positive/negative filter cases very easily, then test your action completely independently. Separation of concerns, ftw!

```
static final Integer RECORD_COUNT = Limits.getLimitQueries() + 1;
static testMethod void testIsFlagged_Positive()
{
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < RECORD_COUNT; i++)
        accounts.add(new Account(Some_Flag__c=true));

    Test.startTest();
        List<Account> results = AccountService.isFlagged().filter(accounts);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(RECORD_COUNT, results.size(), 'message');
}
static testMethod void testIsFlagged_Negative()
{
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < RECORD_COUNT; i++)
        accounts.add(new Account(Some_Flag__c=false));

    Test.startTest();
        List<Account> results = AccountService.isFlagged().filter(accounts);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(0, results.size(), 'message');
}
```

Comment: No. My question is more on the should I collect all the accounts which are invalid and add error for those accounts in a separate loop  or can I just add error for the invalid accounts in the first loop itself. My fear is that if we are importing 200 accounts using dataloader and out of which first account doesn't satisfy the criteria does the trigger process remaining 199 accounts if I use the first approach??

Comment: @javanoob That depends 100% on the calling context, which defines *allOrNone* behavior.

Comment: so If the allOrNone flag is set false, the two patterns behave same??

Comment: Or if it's true. Either way the behavior will not be affected by your pattern, so that should not be a concern in your selection criteria. @javanoob

Comment: +1 for legibility; I like the concept of the Selector framework myself, except that it's far bulkier than it should be.

Comment: @sfdcfox Interesting observation! Curious what you would trim down. I would definitely love to see improvements and I'm sure if anyone still owns the project, they'd welcome them as well. It's a package put together by really smart people I was lucky to work with and learn from. Inspired me to improve my own work.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I love the folk over at Blue Wolf, and it was the Selector package that initially got me in to writing my own. Here's the "select" pattern in one version of my internal library: `Account[] records = (Account[])Data.filterRecords(Trigger.new, new Data.FieldEqualsFilter(Account.Some_Flag__c, true));` If you're interested, I might post a polished version on my blog shortly.

Comment: @sfdcfox Do want. Just started reading it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Both will accomplish what you are after, but I tend to prefer `Snippet 1` because it simply reduces the number of script statements that need to be evaluated.  In `Snippet 2` you are inefficiently iterating twice over the records you want to add the error to (as well as creating more memory overhead by creating another list of records to store temporarily).